# IOS app throws a SIGSEGV exception through TestFlight

Tags: objective-c, testflight

I have an IOS app that I've developed and it works great in the simulator and on my IPOD touch when deployed through xCode. I have tried to share it with a tester through TestFlight; but the app always encounters a SIGSEGV exception. The same exception occurs on my IPOD touch when I load the app via TestFlight; but not when I run the app through xCode on my IPOD touch.

I've done my best to track down the issue and using remote logging and identified the line of code that is failing; it is not clear to me why it is failing, what I can do about it, and why it works through xCode but not TestFlight.

Here is the logging out put:

```
2012-09-16 14:46:41 TestFlight: Crash Handlers are installed
2012-09-16 14:46:41 Bootstrap
2012-09-16 14:46:41 bind settingsLoaded
2012-09-16 14:46:41 adding listeners to map
2012-09-16 14:46:41 listener map {
settingsLoaded = "{(\n)}";
}
2012-09-16 14:46:41 Loading appModel
2012-09-16 14:46:41 Loading settings
2012-09-16 14:46:41 Waiting for data to load
2012-09-16 14:46:42 TestFlight: Team Token is recognized
2012-09-16 14:46:42 Loading settings content
2012-09-16 14:46:42 Loading startScreen
2012-09-16 14:46:42 Loading jpegQuality
2012-09-16 14:46:42 Loading paperSize
2012-09-16 14:46:42 Loading showGrid
2012-09-16 14:46:42 Loading cropMode
2012-09-16 14:46:42 Loading filterType
2012-09-16 14:46:42 Loading adjustAllPages
2012-09-16 14:46:42 Loading settings complete
2012-09-16 14:46:42 triggering settings loaded
2012-09-16 14:46:42 trigger settingsLoaded
2012-09-16 14:46:42 triggerEvent settingsLoaded
2012-09-16 14:46:42 getting listeners from map
```

Here is my header file for the class that is failing

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Gritz.h"

@interface GritzObject : NSObject {

    NSMutableDictionary *listenerMap;
}

#pragma creation

+ (GritzEvent*) create;

#pragma Events

- (void) bind:(void (^)(GritzEvent*))listener forEvent:(NSString*)name;
- (void) unbind:(void (^)(GritzEvent*))listener forEvent:(NSString*)name;
- (void) trigger:(NSString*)name;
- (void) triggerEvent:(GritzEvent*)event;

@end
```

Here is the implementation file for the class that is failing

```
#import "GritzObject.h"
#import "TestFlight.h"

@implementation GritzObject 

#pragma create

+ (GritzObject *)create {

    return [[GritzObject alloc] init];
}

- (id)init {

    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        listenerMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma events

- (void)bind:(void (^)(GritzEvent*))listener forEvent:(NSString *)name {

    TFLog(@"bind %@", name);

    NSMutableSet* listeners = [listenerMap objectForKey:name];

    if(nil == listeners) {

        TFLog(@"adding listeners to map");

        listeners = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

        [listenerMap setValue:listeners forKey:name];

        TFLog(@"listener map %@", listenerMap);
    }

    [listeners addObject:listener];
}

- (void)unbind:(void (^)(GritzEvent*))listener forEvent:(NSString *)name {

    TFLog(@"unbind %@", name);

    NSMutableSet* listeners = [listenerMap objectForKey:name];

    if(nil != listeners) {
        [listeners removeObject:listener];
    }
}

- (void)trigger:(NSString *)name {

    TFLog(@"trigger %@", name);

    [self triggerEvent:[GritzEvent withName:name]];
}

- (void)triggerEvent:(GritzEvent *)event {

    TFLog(@"triggerEvent %@", event.name);

    TFLog(@"getting listeners from map");

    TFLog(@"listener map %@", listenerMap); // This throws a SIGSEGV exception

    NSMutableSet* listeners = [listenerMap objectForKey:event.name];

    TFLog(@"inspecting listeners array");

    if(nil != listeners) {

        for (void (^listener)(GritzEvent*) in listeners) {
            listener(event);
        }
    }
    else {

        TFLog(@"no listeners found for event %@", event.name);
    }
}

@end
```

The exception, as best I can tell from the logging statements, occurs when trying to access the listnerMap. It would appear that this variable is being dereferenced; but it's not clear why or what I can do about it?

I'm using ARC for this application.

Comment: Does it still crash if you remove the line with the SIGSEGV comment? If so, does it crash before or after the next `TFLog(…)`?

Comment: It still crashes if I remove that line. The next TFLog statement "inspecting listeners array" is printed out but that is the last line before it crashes.

Comment: You might need more logging before and after `listener(event)` and at the end of the function. Better still, see if you can get the crash dump via TestFlight and load it up into Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that I was having was fixed by 'copying' the block before storing it in the NSSet. Before storing a block in a collection it must be copied.

I changed this line

```
[listeners addObject:listener];
```

To

```
[listeners addObject:[listener copy]];
```